# Get Tile Data inside Tile Container

Tags: sapui5

I've a custom tiles inside Tile container. which have custom defined properties. I want to get the data of all specific property (Score) for example of all tiles to perform some calculations. 
using `var ctr =   this.byId("overviewTileContainer");` I'm able to get the detail of tile container. I've tried `ctr.getTiles()` but it gives me `[]` how i can get tiles and then property of all tiles. 
[image: Tile Container Data]
Above Image show the result of tile container control. I want to access all dles reside in f0 to f20.

Comment: you can get your data not via the aggregation of a control, but via the list binding, because all the data that are renered, are reneder using the binding path. When it comes to empty array response, are you sure that by that time you are trying to get tiles, the data are loaded and tiles are rendered?

Comment: I'm trying to get tiles on init function. my control holds the detail of tiles. I further need to fetch data from tiles

Comment: in onInit Tiles are not created yet, either put your code in onAfterRendering or compute whatever you need outside the tile container. Plz share more code for more precise answer (like view, binding and what you need to compute) :)

Comment: Here is the code of view.
<TileContainer  id="overviewTileContainer" tiles="{
      path: 'dlScor>/DLES_SOLUTION_CONTENT',
      parameters: {
        
        select: 'ID,LJ_SOLUTION, RESP_TOTAL,DLES'
      }
    }" >
 <tiles>
 
 <dles:DLESScoreTile name="{dlScor>RESP_TOTAL} Responses" topicId="{dlScor>ID}" topic="{dlScor>LJ_SOLUTION}" dles="{dlScor>DLES}"    id="tileDLESCourse"   press=".handleCourseClick"  >
 </dles:DLESScoreTile>
</tiles>
 </TileContainer>

Comment: var ctr =  this.byId("overviewTileContainer"); is init function of my controller..

Comment: you need to get the "tiles" binding of a container and attach the "dataReceived" event. On that point of time, the tiles will be available.

Comment: can you give me any example code. I'm bit confused